# Copying worksheet data from multiple workbooks and pasting it into a master data file by worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am completely newbie to VBA however I was given a task to complete using VBA.  How do I create a code which copies the data of multiple worksheets from different workbooks and pastes them into another workbook (master data file) by adding exactly the same number of separate worksheets to this master data file? That is, I would like to display all of those worksheets being copied over to separate worksheets in the master data file.

I have managed to pull off a code which copies the data over and pastes it into one single worksheet but I am struggling to get them copied over one by one to separate worksheets.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
Sub datatransfer()

    Dim FolderPath, FilePath, Filename, targetfile As String
    Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim i, mycount As Long

    targetfile = "Left the location out on purpose"
    FolderPath = " Left the location out on purpose "
    FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

    Filename = Dir(FilePath)

    Dim lastrow, lastcolumn As Long

    Do While Filename < ""

        mycount = mycount + 1

        Filename = Dir()

        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)

        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(targetfile)

        Worksheets.Add Before:=Sheet1, Count:=2


        For i = 1 To mycount

            With Worksheets(i)

                ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, lastcolumn))

            End With

        Next i

        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

        Filename = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. I made several notes where I modified the code a bit to ensure it works with hitches going forward.

```
Sub datatransfer()

    'have to specify type for all variables, techinically it still works the way you did, but you are setting unncessary memory
    Dim FolderPath As String, FilePath As String, Filename As String, targetfile As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    targetfile = "Left the location out on purpose"
    FolderPath = " Left the location out on purpose "
    FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(targetfile) 'only need to open this once and leave open until execution is finished

    Filename = Dir(FilePath)

    Do While Filename <> "" ' need "<>" to say not equal to nothing

        wb2.Worksheets.Add After:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count) 'add new sheet to paste data in target book

        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)

        Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

        With wb1.Worksheets(1) 'best to qualify all objects and work directly with them
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            'pretty sure you want to add this A1, since it's a new blank sheet
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy _
                Destination:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count).Range("A1")

        End With

        wb1.Close False 'assume no need to save changes to workbook you copied data from

        Filename = Dir

    Loop

    wb2.Close True 'no close and save master file

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, thank you for your time. 

How does " wb2.Worksheets.Add After:=wb.Worksheets.Count " bit take into account that I would like to add worksheets being equal to the number of files? If I modify as "wb1.Worksheets.Count", Run-time error 91 window pops up. At the stage wb2 is still uninitialized.

Each file I copy data from contains only one worksheet thus the number of files in a folder is equal to the number of worksheets to be added. How does the modified code know the number of files in the folderpath? Scott, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Richard - First the line should be `wb2.Worksheets.Add After:=wb2.Worksheets.Count`. Sorry, for the syntax error. `wb2` is initialized before the Loop even starts, so that is good. My code never looks for or finds out the number of files in the path, but rather adds a sheet *(the wb2.Worksheets.Add ... line)* for each time the loop processes and since the loop goes through each `.xls` file in the path a new sheet is added for each file.

Comment: Run-time error 1004 if I initialize it as `wb2`. It is MS Office 2010. It does not copy each sheet to a blank, new one even if there are existing blank worksheets. It dumps the source data onto only one worksheet. Do you suggest I qualify all objects even if there are lots of source files? We may need to copy data from loads of files that is why I am thinking of a `With` structure.  Thanks a lot, Scott.

Comment: @Richard I made one more edit. The syntax was still off. Sorry about that. This line `Destination:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count).Range("A1")` will copy to the last worksheet in the wb2 - which is the newly added worksheet created for that specific file. (I just tested this code fully on my system and it works).

Comment: It works on my system as well. I am immensely grateful for your help.